# Есть ли возможность запретить раскрытие тега details?

Tags: html, css, simple-html-dom, tag

Мне очень симпатичен тег details. Он умеет просто делать то что требуется очень часто. Но я не знаю как грамотно сделать запрет на раскрытие тега. Это мне нужно для того что бы не дублировать форму в тех местах, где это мне не требуется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете установить любой другой обработчик клика. Например:

```html
<details onclick="return false">
    <summary>А я не откроюсь!</summary>
    <p>Контент</p>
</details>
```

Ил способ с использованием `addEventListener`:

```js
document.getElementById('mydetails').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<details id="mydetails">
    <summary>А я не откроюсь!</summary>
    <p>Контент</p>
</details>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Мне первый вариант понравился.  Я сейчас блоки делаю, и думаю насколько это безопасно. Если человек уберёт защиту, он получит доступ к кнопкам управления... Чем дольше собираю, тем больше начинаю задумываться о безопасности кода и как хотя бы теоретически можно  было бы этот процесс контролировать при формировании кода.